# How do I join two variables to create a folder name?

Tags: perl, variables, directory, prompt

What I'm trying to do is create a folder at a designated location and then name that folder with the date and the users initials. I want the user to be able to input the initials when creating the folder. I have figured out how to generate the date in the correct format but I need to figure out how to add the user input $initials together so that the folder name is something like this "130506SS". I can't figure out how to join these two variables together to get the correct folder name. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
    use strict ;
    use warnings ;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $mydate = strftime("%y%m%d",localtime(time)); #puts the year month date and  time in the correct format for the folder name    
    print "Enter users initials: ";
    my $initials = <STDIN>; # prompts for user input 

   #$mydate.= "SS"; #stores today's date and the initials

   $mydate.= $initials;


   sub capture {

   my $directory =  '/test/' . $mydate; 

      unless(mkdir($directory, 0777)) {
           die "Unable to create $directory\n";

           } 

           }        

   capture(); #creates the capture folder 


    sub output {

    my $directory =  '/test2/' . $mydate; 

        unless(mkdir($directory, 0777)) {
            die "Unable to create $directory\n";

            } 

            }       

    output(); #creates the output folder
```

Edit: The entire portion of the above script works except where I'm trying to join the two variable to create the folder name. ($mydate.= $initials;) I've tested it with ($mydate.= "SS";) instead and the script works perfectly. I can manage to join the variable $mydate and a string but not $initials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not indicated which bit you think isn't working, but I suspect it's because you've got an embedded newline in the folder/file name that you create.

With the below you have $mydate initialised to a date string and $initials with a line from STDIN:

```
my $mydate = strftime("%y%m%d",localtime(time));
my $initials = <STDIN>;
```

The thing to note here is that $initials has a newline character at the end of the input; before joining them you'll want to get rid of that newline. The following code will do what you want:

```
chomp ($initials);
$mydate .= $initials;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get an error: "Unable to create /test/130506SS".

One problem is that [mkdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) cannot recursively create a directory, but you can use `make_path` from [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

Another issue is that you should `chomp` your input.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Path qw(make_path);
my $mydate = strftime( "%y%m%d", localtime(time) );    #puts the year month date and  time in the correct format for the folder name
print "Enter users initials: ";
my $initials = <STDIN>;                                # prompts for user input
chomp $initials;
#$mydate.= "SS"; #stores today's date and the initials

$mydate .= $initials;

sub capture {
    my $directory = '/test/' . $mydate;
    unless ( make_path( $directory) ) {
        die "Unable to create $directory\n";
    }
}

capture();    #creates the capture folder
```